# Web.Config Custom Error not re-directing to error page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to create custom Error in my Web.Config file and only Error 404 works. When I'm trying to re-direct to "Access Denied" (401/403) page it re-directs me to my Login Page and in the URL it just says

> login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fIndex.aspx

My Web.Config file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  

  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DVDRental.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/AccessDenied.aspx" mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/AccessDenied.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="402" redirect="~/AccessDenied.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/AccessDenied.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/noPage.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.web>   
    
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ConnString" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ConnString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ConnString" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ConnString" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v13.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  
  <location path="Manager">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Manager"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  
  <location path="Bartosz">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin1, Manager"/>        
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  
  <location path="Sam">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin2, Manager"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Paul">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin3, Manager"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Chris">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin4, Manager"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Index.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin4"/>
        <allow roles="Admin3"/>
        <allow roles="Admin2"/>
        <allow roles="Admin1"/>
        <allow roles="Manager"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  
</configuration>
```

I have also tried Setting the mode to "On" and it still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by you are trying to redirect? If the user tries to access a restricted page, the system should do that part.

Comment: @SirajK I want to re-direct them to "AccessDenied" page not to login.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that your other (redirect) aspx pages are not covered by your security rules. So you are redirecting to them, but don't have permissions to view them, until you login.

Try adding this to your web.config

```
<location path="AccessDenied.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Still no luck with that.